# Creating a Javascript array using JSON response from ajax

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, json

I am trying to query a database to get some rows of data that I can use in a JavaScript array.  The format of the array should be like this so I can use it later.

```
var data = [
    {
        column1: 'Test 1',
        column2: 'Some Test'
    },
    {
        column1: 'Test 2',
        column2: 'Another Test'
    },
    {
        column1: 'Test 3',
        column2: 'Yet Another Test'
    }
];
```

This is how i get the rows from the database

```
 var data = new Array();

 $.ajax({
        url : 'util/getJSON.php',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function (response) {

        }        
    });
```

My php file that creates the JSON

```
$sql = "SELECT column1, column2 FROM table";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

$array = array();

foreach($rows as $key => $row) {
    $array[$key]['column1'] = $row['column1']; 
    $array[$key]['column2'] = $row['column2'];
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

The problem is I don't know how to create the JavaScript array using the JSON response in the ajax call.

**EDIT:**

I need to use the data array later like this

```
// Loop through the array

for(var i in data){
    if(data[i].name.match($search)){
        $suggestedUL.append($("<li><span class='suggest-name'>" + data[i].name + "</span><span class='suggest-description'>" + data[i].description + "</span></li>"));
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the output in the console?

Comment: why do you want to create an array? Why do not use the json object?

Comment: JSON is basically javascript. `response` is going to be the javascript equivalent of the data structure you encoded in PHP, e.g. it'll be a object. You told jquery to expect JSON, so jquery will automatically decode the JSON string that php sent out and turn it into a native javascript structure. `console.log(response)` would show you exactly what you received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ajax:**

```
var data = new Array();

$.ajax({
    url : 'util/getSupplierList.php',
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    async: false,
    success : function (response) {
        data = JSON.stringify(response);
    }        
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: The reason I used the loop was because it added more to the array. I had `{'column 1': 'Test 1', '0': Test 1', 'Column 2' : 'Test 2', '1' : 'Test 2'}`

Comment: Oh ok from the example you showed you dont need it, but if you have good reaons in real time then use the loop, it is only useful if you need to modify the data

Comment: @AdRock did I answer your question ?

Comment: Nearly. How do i use the response to create an array like i posted above so i can use it later outside the loop?

Comment: @AdRock response is already the array, or did I misunderstand you ?

Comment: I need to use that response outside of the success function so i need to create an object/array with the data from the response. I create an array using `var data = new Array();` which might be wrong but i need to loop through the response and add the response to the data variable so i can use it later in a for loop (see edit)

Comment: I get an empty array but if i put `console.log(response)` in the success function i get `[Object, Object, Object...]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63877/discussion-between-meda-and-adrock).

Answer (score 0):

Within the success function, iterate through the response JSON array.

```
$.each(response, function(index, item) {
    data[index]["column1"] = $(item).column1;
    data[index]["column2"] = $(item).column2;
}
```